# ReactJS—mouseOut firing on hover of child element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a div with moueOver and mouseOut functions. 
Why is the mouseOut firing when I hover over one of the children? This is in a list so I need to use e.target vs. hard coding the '.thumb-overlay'. It's also tweaking the backgrounds of the h2 and h4 inside and I don't quite understand.
Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/69z2wepo/48641/).

```
<div className="thumb-overlay"
 onMouseOver={this.mouseOver.bind(this)}
 onMouseOut={this.mouseOut.bind(this)}>
 <h2>SOME H2 TAG</h2>  
 <h4>SOME H4 TAG</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats how mouseOut works I think. Check out the difference between those and mouseEnter/mouseLeave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`. `e.currentTarget` always refers to the element the event handler has been attached to as opposed to `e.target`

```
mouseOver(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).css('background', 'red');
}
mouseOut(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).css('background', 'gray');
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/48649/)